# Facebook App to post to Facebook Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

Can someone please provide an up-to-date guide on how to setup a Facebook App linked to a Business Page to allow posting from an external website?

I have created a Website with Facebook Login App and I am using the JavaScript SDK to posting of content from our website to our Business Page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "OURAPPID", status: true, cookie: true, frictionlessRequests: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'http://www.ourdoamin.com/test.jsp',
      picture: 'http://www.ourdoamin.com/image.jpg',
      name: 'Test Article',
      caption: 'Here We GO',
      description: 'This is a test.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

When I click the Post to Feed link, I am presented with a dialogue box, the App is correctly identified in the Via field and if I enter a status and click Share, I receive a Post ID.

However, despite the app being correctly referenced and receiving a Post ID, the post actually appears on the Wall of the users account currently logged in and not the Business page.

I would prefer no login at all, just a straight post using the App to the Business Page and not a users individual account.

Can someone, please tell me where I am going wrong and how to correct this?

Comment: The Feed dialog has a `to`parameter … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Thank you, I added the respective email address of the Business Page accounts as follows:

    FB.init({appId: "OURAPPID", status: true, cookie: true, frictionlessRequests: true, to: 'my@emailcom'});

It did change the account picture, but depite getting a Post ID, the post still did not appear on the Business Page Wall.

Comment: Adding it as a parameter to FB.init is completely useless – as I said, it’s a parameter of the _Feed dialog_ …

Comment: Apologies, for placing the parameter in the wrong function. If I'm logged in as an administrator or other profile, it allows the post to be made, but appears in the section Recent Posts by Others. If I'm logged in as the main account user of the Business Page I get the following error:

An invalid target was specified: 391723550881677. The target must be a page, event, or user that the actor can post on the wall of.

Is there a way to have the post to appear as the main account holder?

Comment: What do you mean by “main account holder”, an admin of that page or what? If so – get a user access token from the admin. Otherwise, you can also get a page access token if you want the posts to appear to be made by the page itself.

Comment: The error occured as I was logged on as the Business Page account and not that of a related admin account or other facebook user. With regards to page access token, can this be used with Feed Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can post directly to a page using the page `access_token`. In order to do this, you will need the `manage_pages` permission. Once you ask for the permission, you can get the page `access_token` by calling `/me/accounts` and noting the correct token for the page you want to post to.

Use this `access_token` in your API call to post to the page as an administrator / page.

Comment: I followed the steps found in this article:

http://www.testically.org/2011/09/27/5-steps-to-automatically-write-on-your-facebook-page-wall-using-the-graph-api-without-a-logged-in-user/

But if I get this right I cannot use the code above I need to used https://graph.facebook.com instead. If so could you please give me an idea as how to code the demo above but instead use Graph API instead.

Comment: You basically do the same things in the Graph. Call `{page_id}/feed` and post the data you want to the page (as in your code).